# spresesnse cameraモジュールからRAW画像の取得

Tags: spresense

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/introduction/
にRAW画像が取得できるとあるのですが、V4SのレイヤーからRAW画像を取得することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご指摘の機能についてですが、
SpresenseのカメラボードではRAW画像の取得は出来ない仕様となっております。

こちら、ドキュメントの記載に不備がございました。
ドキュメントを修正しましたので、ご確認いただければと思います。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム